# Positioning table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

The below command works in `.tex` file to move the position of table of contents.

```
\frame {
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \hfill
  \parbox{.73\textwidth}{
    \tableofcontents
  }
}
```

But I want to do the same from `.sty` files. How can I do it?

Comment: What you're doing here is perfectly reasonable from within your `.tex` source. To try and include this within a `.sty` file seems to defeat the purpose (due to the size of the requirement) - see [Modifying `.sty` files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47354/5764). Why do you need *this* in a `.sty` file?