# Writing to and extracting from aux not working?

Tags: lengths, auxiliary-files

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\templen}
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\setlength{\noexpand\templen}{150pt}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\typeout{Document start}
\verb!1:! \the\templen \par
\setlength{\templen}{100pt}
\verb!2:! \the\templen
\end{document}
```

Compiling twice gives the output

```
1: 0.0pt
2: 100.0pt
```

even though the `.aux` contains

```
\relax 
\setlength {\templen }{150pt}
```

According to the `.log`, the `.aux` is read before the document start as indicated by `\typeout`:

```
 (./latex_stuff.aux)% <------------- This is where the .aux is read
\openout1 = `latex_stuff.aux'.
%...
Document start      % <------------- This is the document start
```

So, why doesn't the output resemble

```
1: 150.0pt
2: 100.0pt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.aux` file is read within a group, and `\setlength` is a local command. Handily, you can use a prefix with `\setlength` (not sure if this is documented):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\templen}
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
    {\noexpand\global\noexpand\setlength{\noexpand\templen}{150pt}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\typeout{Document start}
\verb!1:! \the\templen \par
\setlength{\templen}{100pt}
\verb!2:! \the\templen
\end{document}
```

Here's an extract of the definition of `\document` (called with an issue of `\begin{document}`) that loads the `.aux` file. It clearly shows the localized scope within which the `.aux` is read (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\document{\endgroup
  \ifx\@unusedoptionlist\@empty\else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Unused global option(s):^^J%
            \@spaces[\@unusedoptionlist]}%
  \fi
  \@colht\textheight
  \@colroom\textheight \vsize\textheight
  \columnwidth\textwidth
  \@clubpenalty\clubpenalty
  \if@twocolumn
    \advance\columnwidth -\columnsep
    \divide\columnwidth\tw@ \hsize\columnwidth \@firstcolumntrue
  \fi
  \hsize\columnwidth \linewidth\hsize
  \begingroup\@floatplacement\@dblfloatplacement% <-- Group start
    \makeatletter\let\@writefile\@gobbletwo
    \global \let \@multiplelabels \relax
    \@input{\jobname.aux}%                        <-- .aux read in
  \endgroup%                                      <-- Group end
  % ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work when `calc` is loaded. I'd go with `\global\templength=150pt\relax` (none of these tokens is expandable).