# How to center sections and subsections in beamer using \tableofcontents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

How do I center (or even just simply increase the left margin of) the outline produced by `\tableofcontents` in beamer?

Normal tools like `\centering` or `\begin{center}..\end{center}` do not work because the list should be left-aligned, but appearing in the center.

Environments like `minipage`, `columns` also do not work because, as mentioned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38165/234309), beamer collapses the vertical spacing.

The proposed solution in the linked answer also doesn't work because subsection bullets, for some reason, are oblivious to the `\leftskip` parameter.

Thank you!

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[xelatex, aspectratio=169, 10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  %\begin{columns}[c]
    %\begin{column}{0.9\textwidth}
      \setlength{\leftskip}{0.1\textwidth}
      \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
      \setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
      \tableofcontents
    %\end{column}
  %\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\section{Intro section}
\subsection{Case alpha}
\begin{frame}
  Frame 1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Case beta}
\begin{frame}
  Frame 2
\end{frame}


\section{Results}
\subsection{First experiment}
\begin{frame}
  Frame 3
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second experiment}
\begin{frame}
  Frame 4
\end{frame}

\subsection{Third experiment}
\begin{frame}
  Frame 5
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a bit of horizontal space to the `subsection in toc` template:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  %\begin{columns}[c]
    %\begin{column}{0.9\textwidth}
      \setlength{\leftskip}{0.4\textwidth}
      \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
      \setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
      \addtobeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace{.4\textwidth}}{}
      \tableofcontents
    %\end{column}
  %\end{columns}
\end{frame}


\section{Intro section}
\subsection{Case alpha}
\begin{frame}
  Frame 1
\end{frame}

\subsection{Case beta}
\begin{frame}
  Frame 2
\end{frame}


\section{Results}
\subsection{First experiment}
\begin{frame}
  Frame 3
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second experiment}
\begin{frame}
  Frame 4
\end{frame}

\subsection{Third experiment}
\begin{frame}
  Frame 5
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks. Very adhoc-y (:

Comment: @gsarret You're welcome!